# OpenStack: add security rules failed due to multiple security groups named with "default"

Tags: openstack, devstack

After installed devstack, I follow the [doc](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/networking.html#defaults) to set security rules:

```
$ openstack security group rule create --proto icmp --dst-port 0 default
More than one security_group exists with the name 'default'.
```

It claims I have multiple security_group which named with `default`, but I check with `nova secgroup-list`:

```
$ nova secgroup-list
WARNING: Command secgroup-list is deprecated and will be removed after Nova 15.0.0 is released. Use python-neutronclient or python-openstackclient instead.
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
| Id                                   | Name    | Description            |
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
| e5466481-f656-46fa-ac72-56f7ab118c70 | default | Default security group |
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
```

So, there is only one security group named with `default`...

Could any one give me some suggestion about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's a common problem when you have multiple tenants, each with a "default" group. The solution I have applied before is to use the group ID instead of the group name when it comes to the "default" group.